# How to make form submit different button when I press enter on different text input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

For example, I have this form:

```
<form action="destination.jsp" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="Productqty1"/>
    <input type="text" name="Productqty2"/>
    <input type="text" name="Productqty3"/>
    <input type="submit" name="RecalculatePrice" value="Recalculate Price"/>

    <input type="text" name="ZipCode"/>
    <input type="submit" name="RecalculateShipping" value="Recalculate Shipping"/>

    <input type="text" name="Offercode"/>
    <input type="submit" name="RecalculateDisc" value="Recalculate Discount"/>

    <input type="submit" name="CheckOut"/>
</form>
```

I need that if the user press enter on Productqty1, Productqty2, or Productqty3, then the default action is suppressed, and button RecalculatePrice is clicked instead.

And the same goes with if user press enter on ZipCode, the RecalculateShipping button gets clicked instead. The same with Offercode input and RecalculateOffercode button.

But if the user press on CheckOut button, the whole form must be still submitted. That's why they're on the same form, multiple submit button on the same form.

I also need to suppress the default action of enter key, because IE8 did not sent button submit value along with the form submit, so let's disable it altogether to avoid confusion.

How can I find a unified solution for this? It's okay if it has to be made in multiple javascript function, just as long as I can understand the solution pattern, because form with multiple submit button and user can press enter on any input field is confusing me. JQuery solutions are welcomed. Thanks.

EDIT: sorry for the poor choice of words that lead to confusion. What I mean with suppress default action is that when you press enter, the form get submitted, using any (random?) button submit. That is the default behavior I want to suppress.

Comment: Is Google down for you? https://www.google.com.au/#safe=off&q=jquery+prevent+enter+submitting+form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added classes and id for each submit button(added id) and text box(added class).

Try this

```
<form action="destination.jsp" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="Productqty1" class="class1"/>
    <input type="text" name="Productqty2" class="class1"/>
    <input type="text" name="Productqty3" class="class1"/>
    <input type="submit" name="RecalculatePrice" value="Recalculate Price" id="class1"/>
    <input type="text" name="ZipCode"  class="class2"/>
    <input type="submit" name="RecalculateShipping" value="Recalculate Shipping" id="class2"/>
    <br><br>
    <input type="text" name="Offercode"  class="class3"/>
    <input type="submit" name="RecalculateDisc" value="Recalculate Discount" id="class3"/>

    <input type="submit" name="CheckOut"/>

</form>
```

Script

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".class1").keypress(function (event) {
        if (event.which == 13) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $('#class1').click();
        }
    });
    $(".class2").keypress(function (event) {
        if (event.which == 13) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $('#class2').click();
        }
    });
    $(".class3").keypress(function (event) {
        if (event.which == 13) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $('#class3').click();
        }
    });
});
```

Fiddle [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VLZGk/843/)

Comment: This seems to be the solution for me. Let me try to apply it, and return with feedback. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @ChenLiYong any result??

Comment: @Nirajan N Raju Hi. Sorry for the late reply. Actually, I'm facing different issue, not related with your code, but it preventing the page contained your code to be compiled. Please wait for a little bit more.

Comment: @ChenLiYong Glad i could help you. consider accepting and upvoting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would argue that `CheckOut` is your special scenario here. While you could certainly catch the enter key and invoke different actions, there are primarily two reasons why I don't find that to be the optimal solution here:

1. Your IE8 concern seems to negate the entire prior discussion, and in my mind, this should advise you to look in another direction. Don't do a special solution for IE8, do something that all supported browsers can understand.
2. There is no field for which `CheckOut` should be the default action on enter.

I suggest that you make different forms, *and* use different actions, rather than checking which button was clicked by inspecting the name parameter of the button.

On click of the CheckOut-button, which should never be triggered by an enter key, you should submit all forms. You can serialize their combined values and post them like so:

```
$('#product-form, #zip-form, #offer-form').serialize();
```

Comment: This is a solution that I hope every browser understand. I would like to suppress the default behavior for enter for all browsers, and have them click the appropriate button. Anyway, I also think like what you think at the beginning. But the code from previous developers is already very convoluted that I'm afraid I might ended up breaking things rather than fixing if I changed it. Believe me, if cleaning up this particular code is not that complex, I would rather do that first.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery/javascript function to change the form.action before submitting the page. 
Submit type should submit the form to default form action, which has been added on form declaration.

```
    <form action="destination.jsp" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="Productqty1"/>
    <input type="text" name="Productqty2"/>
    <input type="text" name="Productqty3"/>
    <input type="button" name="RecalculatePrice" value="Recalculate Price"/ onClick="callDefault();">

    <input type="text" name="ZipCode"/>
    <input type="button" name="RecalculateShipping" value="Recalculate Shipping"/ onClick="callRecalculateShipping();">

    <input type="text" name="Offercode"/>
    <input type="button" name="RecalculateDisc" value="Recalculate Discount"/ onClick="callRecalculateDisc();">

    <input type="button" name="CheckOut"/ onClick="callCheckout();">
</form>
<javascript>
function callCheckout(){
form.action="<some value>";
form.submit();
}
...so on with other functions... 
</javascript>
```

Change input types to button .

Comment: My question seems to raise confusion, and I'm truly sorry about that. I wasn't tried to change or suppress the form `action` (the page destination), but I was trying to suppress the form behavior that automatically submit the form if the user press enter, along with then doing some other things like clicking particular button. I hope this cleared up the confusion. Thanks.